# How much RAM Does My Program Use? Memory Profiling Report Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory, memory-management, performance-testing

I am trying to figure out how much RAM my program needs.  I am running a C# console application that access a SQL Database.  When I check it out in the Task Manager, it is in the neighborhood of 27 MB but when I run the Memory Profiling Report, I get the results below.  I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me understand this.  I have searched the internet and SO and have not been able to figure out a number that I can count on.  I would ballpark it but the results are just too different.   Thanks for any help at all :)

To clarify:  Knowing this, what can I tell my hardware person when they ask me how much memory to specify for the server for this process?

[image: memory profiling report "total bytes allocated"]

Comment: Remember, **RAM has not been the same thing as memory for decades now**. You are best off thinking of memory as disk space, and RAM as a fast cache on top of the disk.  The amount of RAM you need to ensure good performance is equal to the number of pages that are paged in from disk in the *working set*.  What are you really asking with this question?

Comment: You can use _Performance Monitor_ (aka Perfmon) to look at various memory statistics. Be aware that there are many ways at looking at memory use in a virtual memory environment like Windows. Also be aware of how a garbage collected program runs; it looks like it has a memory leak, and then periodically stair-steps down eventually. That's normal. Also note that x86 and x64 memory use will be different.

Comment: @EricLippert -- I updated the question but basically I am trying to make sure the server that I get has enough RAM to run the process.

Comment: Then what you want to look at is not raw memory usage, but things like how big your working set is, whether you are thrashing the disk, and so on. A program can reserve ten billion bytes if it wants, and if it never maps it in to virtual memory, that's not relevant to your problem.  But if you need a thousand pages of memory in the working set and you have 990 available, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAM only contributes as a random access. Computing power is dictated by processing speed/power, therefore, if a heavily fluctuating RAM usage is noticeable, upgrading the RAM itself is not ideal. From what I can tell, it appears that the program requires at least 2gb of RAM to run smoothly and *not* affect other programs running simultaneously on the same processor.

Another method is to calculate an "average" RAM usage during peak processing (ie. while the program is running during full use). Record the RAM consumption at 2 minute intervals for 20 minutes and divide by 10 to get the average "recommended" RAM.

But, like I said, RAM is only part of the power.

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful :)   I am being asked by the hardware people how much RAM my program uses so they can figure out how to configure the server.  I will run some more testing and use what you taught me here.

Comment: Also -- so you are saying the bar on the right is MB of RAM and not percentage of available RAM?

Comment: I've edited my comment. I misinterpreted the byte size allocated for the program, therefore changed my answer to a minimum of 2gb of RAM minimum. The bar on the right appears to be in percentages, not RAM - yes. The total byte size allocation and the fluctuation to 100% tells me that at some point, whatever the ram size is now has used 100% of nearly 2gb of RAM already, so that would be the minimum. An ideal upgrade in RAM would be to 4gb of RAM, but again, CPU speed is important as well - if the CPU can't handle processes faster than 800mhz then it's pointless really to upgrade the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to gain are usages which related to your application (sql usage which use resource to execute your command) i can not possible because they are use ram as different resources.

first you should know that we have different type of memory and each tool show the one of them , for more info you can see this article
[Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153053/what-is-the-right-way-to-monitor-application-memory-usage)
if you want to calculate your own application you have multiple options :

1.you can run your program under debug mode in vs 2015 or higher and activate diagnosis tool and see ram usage of your program

2.you can install jetBrains tool or some similar tools that which help you to see how much your application used memory and even its give you much more details such as how many your methods had been called.

3. you can use some .net method which used for calculating ram usage

Comment: I didn't see that page.  Thank you.  I appreciate your help :)